# Get Apache2 to restart after reboot, ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apache2

I installed apache as follows on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install apache2
```

It served my test pages fine. Now I tested a reboot of the machine, and I can't reach the server. I try:

```
$ service apache2 status
```

and get:

```
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
  Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
       └─apache2-systemd.conf
  Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2016-08-16 20:13:45 UTC; 6min ago
  Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1111 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Process: 2624 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

How can I get apache to restart on reboot?

-- Edit -------------------------------------------------------

As per @mouseclone's suggestion, I ran:

```
sudo systemctl enable apache2.service
```

output:

```
apache2.service is not a native service, redirecting to systemd-sysv-install
Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable apache2
```

still no change though, reboot and then apache is down.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04 uses systemd.

General instructions: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/systemd-essentials-working-with-services-units-and-the-journal

`sudo systemctl enable nginx.service`

Comment: I tried running that command, no errors - tried a reboot - still nothing. I also checked the apache2 error.log file, but it's empty.

Comment: I updated it to systemd information.

Comment: Huh ok so I ran that, updated Q with the output, still no luck, though.

Answer (score 0):

Strange.. though you could add `@reboot service apache2 start` to crontab to start apache2 service on boot.
You can access crontab using `crontab -e` command